# Record trigger flow decision to determine all trigger scenarios?

Tags: visual-workflow

I'm looking to consolidate some of our flows so we don't have 10 different account fast field update flows, but just one per object.  This is mainly to make it easier to maintain between a group of admins.

Ideally, I would have one flow with the first decision determining the trigger context - e.g. a record is created or updated, a record is created etc...

[image]

I'm not sure how to accomplish this in a decision node.  E.G. if I start with isnew decision, then how would I also have the decision if it's new or updated?  Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Salesforce used to recommend a single flow per object, but now recommend multiple flows with targeted (and clear) single roles and responsibilities. You can control order of flow executions, handy if there are dependencies.

Comment: Phil, can you provide some references?  Genuinely curious as I'm looking for best practices on managing a lot of flows.

Comment: The order of execution was added in [Spring 22](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_builder_trigger_order.htm&release=236&type=5). It was covered briefly on [medium.com](https://medium.com/ragamuffin-admin/its-official-multiple-flows-per-object-is-a-thing-and-other-flow-related-highlights-spring-22-54888c9c7c4e#:~:text=%231%3A%20You%20Can%20Create%20Multiple,to%20one%20of%20two%20options.) and is touched on in this [admin blog](https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2021/the-ultimate-guide-to-flow-best-practices-and-standards) (though this predates ordering).

Comment: (That admin blog was refreshed Spring 23, so the text can be read in context of having order of execution control, I guess)

Comment: Thanks, I still see value in trying to consolidate flows by object and trigger.  I don't see how the trigger explorer prevent an admin team from using the same criteria in multiple flows which seems inefficient.

Comment: If it is the same criteria, one assumes it would relate to the same process (in most cases), so should go in the same flow. That is why naming and purpose are really important.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a formula varaible for ISNEW().  Use that variable in decision critierion and combine that with an ISCHANGED() criterion in custom logic.

Example:

1. MyField__c is not null
2. IsNew variable is true
3. MyField__c IsChanged = true

1 AND (2 OR 3)